# container on hover with text as single line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="red hover flex">
    <h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="blue hover flex">
    <h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="green hover flex">
    <h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  /* create the flex container */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flex {
  flex: 1;
}
.hover:hover {
  flex: 4;
}
/* colours */
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Hi friends, I want the text in the container not to change its width, whatever the box width may be. The line should come in a single line, I need like the similar format for which link is given below. can anyone help me...Thanks in Advance.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**Set your hovered flex item to not shrink, and it will keep its text in a single line of text.**

If I understand correctly, you want to:

- display several flex items with some text side by side
- if one of the flex items is hovered, it should become bigger up until the point all of its text is in a single line
- the change in size of the hovered item should have an animated transition, like the linked example

Flex items want to be as big as their `max-content` size most of the time, so what we need to do is tell them to stop shrinking when there’s not enough space. We will do this on `:hover`.

Please note that if you force your text to display in a single line, and the other flex items can’t shrink any further, then your flex items will become wider than the screen, and will overflow.

Here’s a working solution of what I described above:

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* transition: flex 500ms cubic-bezier(0.09, 0.76, 0.52, 1); */
  transition: flex 300ms;
}
.flex-item:hover {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
/* colours */
.red {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="red flex-item">
    <h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="blue flex-item">
    <h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="green flex-item">
    <h1>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess the solution was not the correct one, here when i hover the first box, the second and third box should not change its width, the first box should overlap the second box that is, it should be in top of the second box vice versa for the rest of the boxes